# What is the deep instrument in the track 'The Boxer' by Simon & Garfunkel?

Tags: instrument-identification

Towards the end of the song, while they are singing "Lie la lie lie lie lie lie," around 4:19, a very deep instrument joins the song for its closing moments, emitting blasts like an organ.

What is this instrument?

Below is the track:

Comment: Probably made by a synth - however, questions such as this usually get closed, as they are not within the site's remit. Please read about that - maybe the question could be re-phrased to make it a good fit.

Comment: Hmm did you make that comment before or after it was migrated?

Comment: its the same as "last of the mohicans " end music i think

Answer (score 8):

It has been stated that Paul Beaver contributed a Moog synth sound to the track.
See this, in the comments to http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=2751

*Jesse from Madison, Wi*
You know I love to add knowledge when it includes synthesizers - debunking peoples' hatred for those "fake instruments". I heard Paul Beaver made an appearance in the studio and added his famous Moog at the end of the song. Listen closely folks! That's a Moog synthesizer. I don't know that it was Paul Beaver's, but it's a synth nonetheless. Big sounding. And that snare! I think it was just a big snare recorded in a "live room" and run through a tape echo and gated, it's what it sounds like to me - but who am I to judge?

Comment: Nice find. Definitely sounds like a MiniMoog to me - by that I mean though it can't be a mini at that time, it sure ain't an ARP ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moog_synthesizer mentions S&G using one, but is less specific about which track.

Comment: Hi, ctrl+F'ing for "beaver," "moog," and "synth" on that page don't give me any matches-- am I missing something?

Comment: Look in the Comments section.

Comment: Geez that is a pretty iffy source-- no journalist would ever accept that. An unknown commenter on the internet saying "They heard..." I wish we could find something more definitive, even if it's true.

Comment: A journalist would leap at it!  But yes, a scholar would consider it very weak evidence.

Answer (score 2):

You can hear Joe Zawinul using a similar analog synthesiser timbre here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k99aTXYQrNU from 0.24 to 0.40. Whether or not the same ship left NYC in 1970 and docked in Gibraltar five years later is lost in the fog/s of time.